# A question about Feynman diagram and symmetry factor

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, supersymmetry, feynman-diagrams

Consider a $\varphi^3$ theory:
$$
Z_1(J) \propto \exp\left[\frac{i}{6} Z_g g\int \mathrm{d}^4 x \left(\frac{1}{i}\frac{\delta}{\delta J}\right)^3\right] Z_0(J),
$$ 
where 
$$
Z_0(J) = \exp\left[\frac{i}{2} \int \mathrm{d}^4 x \mathrm{d}^4 x' J(x)\Delta(x-x')J(x')\right].
$$
That is
$$
Z_1(J) \propto \sum_{V=0}^\infty \frac{1}{V!}\left[\frac{i}{6} Z_g g \int \mathrm{d}^4 x \, \left(\frac{1}{i}\frac{\delta}{\delta J}\right)^3\right]^V \times \sum_{P=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{P!}\left[\frac{i}{2} \int \mathrm{d}^4 y  \, \,\mathrm{d}^4 z\,  J(y)\Delta(y-z)J(z)\right]^P.
$$
In particular, we can consider the term when $V=2, P=3$. Calculation shows that
\begin{equation}
- i \frac{1}{2!}\frac{1}{3!} \frac{(Z_g g)^2}{6^2*2^3} \left[\int \mathrm{d}^4\,  x_1 \, \mathrm{d}^4 x_2 \, \left(\frac{\delta}{\delta J(x_1)}\right)^3 \left(\frac{\delta}{\delta J(x_2)}\right)^3\right] \left[\int \mathrm{d}^4 y \, \mathrm{d}^4 z \, J(y)\Delta(y-z)J(z)\right]^3\\=
- i \frac{1}{2!}\frac{1}{3!} \frac{(Z_g g)^2}{6^2*2^3} \int \mathrm{d}^4 x_1 \, \mathrm{d}^4 x_2 \,  \left[3^3*2^4 \Delta(x_1-x_1)\Delta(x_1-x_2)\Delta(x_2-x_2) +  \\ 3^2\times 2^5\Delta(x_1-x_2)\Delta(x_1-x_2)\Delta(x_1-x_2)\right]\\=
-i(Z_g g)^2 \int \mathrm{d}^4 x_1 \, \mathrm{d}^4 x_2\, \times \left[\frac{1}{2^3} \Delta(x_1-x_1)\Delta(x_1-x_2)\Delta(x_2-x_2) + \\ \frac{1}{2\times 3!}\Delta(x_1-x_2)\Delta(x_1-x_2)\Delta(x_1-x_2)\right],
\end{equation}
where $\Delta(x_1-x_1)\Delta(x_1-x_2)\Delta(x_2-x_2)$ and $\Delta(x_1-x_2)\Delta(x_1-x_2)\Delta(x_1-x_2)$ correspond to their Feynman diagram. Then the question is why $\frac{1}{2^3}$ and $\frac{1}{2\times 3!}$ are just the reciprocal of symmetry factors of the corresponding Feynman diagram respectively?

In the general case of $V, P$, why the coefficients of the terms in the result of calculation are just the reciprocal of symmetry factors of the corresponding Feynman diagram respectively?

Comment: I applaud you for writing that much LaTeX, but please use the properly scaled brackets for clarity next time,  e.g. 'left[', '\right]' and '\left(', '\right).'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the point of the symmetry factor.

Let's call the term in $Z$ that we're considering $T$.
Without considering the symmetric exchanges that produce the symmetry factor, the contribution of each diagram to $T$ is simply its associated term without any numerical factor in front (a factor of 1). This is because when we count every possible exchange of vertices, propagators, derivatives, etc. that leaves the Feynman diagram invariant, this number neatly cancels out the factorials in the Taylor expansion and our choice of 1/6 and 1/2 in the field Lagrangian. If the symmetry factor for a diagram is 1, each of these exchanges gives rise to an identical term in the $T$. 

 When a diagram has a  symmetry factor that is not 1, some of these exchanges mentioned above no give rise to additional terms. Hence the contribution of that particular diagram must be divide by the symmetry factor $S$.

This is a confusing topic, I wrote a note specifically on this kind of counting [here](http://jakebian.com/theory/counting/)

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the last paragraph in details? The key point may be there.

Comment: It would help if you tell me exactly which part you do not understand.

Comment: Why if 'some of these exchanges mentioned above no give rise to additional terms' then 'the contribution of that particular diagram must be divide by the symmetry factor $S$'?

Comment: So let's consider your example of V=2 and P=3, you can only draw 2 distinct Feynman diagrams for thus case, this tells you that there are two types of terms, I.e. Any term you get from doing the P=3 V=2 integral is identical to one of the Feynman diagrams, the question left is then how many identical terms are there that correspond to each diagram

Comment: And by counting arguments (By the notation I'm assuming you're using Srednicki, he outlines these counting arguments), we can show that if every exchange of vertices, propagators, etc that leaves the diagram invariant correspond to an identical term that contributes, the number of identical terms cancel the Taylor coefficients.

Comment: But in the case that not every such exchange gives a contribution, namely that is when some combination of exchanges point to the same contribution, we DEFINE the symmetry factor S such that when we divide by S, webobtain the correct contribution from each diagram.

Comment: Thanks so much! It will be perfect if you explain why 'each such combination will only be integrated over once' in your note.

Comment: It's not just those combinations that are summed over once, any particular combination contributes only once to the sum. If you look at the explicit integral (first equation in the note), we integrate over $d^4y_1d^4z_1...$. Doing this integral is literally summing over every single combination of $y_1, z_1, y_2,...$, exactly once. The reason we divide by the symmetry factor is in our previous counting, we counted some of the identical combinations more than once.

Comment: Link is dead. Any chance you could update it?